# Joining two tables with two users name information in a row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table_resident like in image below

[image]

And then i have a table_complaints like image below

[image]

with the table_resident.resident_id = table_complaints.resident_id and also table_resident.resident_id = table_complaints.party_id

How can i join resident_id = 1 and party_id = 2 name in same row like image below?  I can see resident_id = 1 first_name, last_name but in resident_id = 2 how can i see them again by using party_id?

[image]

Here is my code in joining but in party_id i dont know what i will use the firstname, lastname, middlename again

```sql
SELECT
  table_involvement.*,
  table_resident.first_name,
  table_resident.last_name, 
  table_resident.middle_name,
  table_complaints.*
FROM ((
  table_complaints
    LEFT JOIN table_resident
      ON table_complaints.resident_id = table_resident.resident_id)
    LEFT JOIN table_involvement
      ON table_complaints.complaints_id = table_involvement.complaints_id)
ORDER BY table_resident.first_name ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.  I user 2 inner joins to achieve this solution.

```
SELECT TABLE_RESIDENT.FIRST_NAME, TABLE_RESIDENT.LAST_NAME, 
TABLE_RESIDENT.MIDDLE_NAME, TABLE_COMPLAINTS.*, TABLE_INVOLVEMENT.* 
FROM TABLE_RESIDENT
INNER JOIN TABLE_COMPLAINTS 
ON TABLE_COMPLAINTS.RESIDENT_ID = TABLE_RESIDENT.RESIDENT_ID
INNER JOIN TABLE_INVOLVEMENT
ON TABLE_COMPLAINTS.RESIDENT_ID = TABLE_INVOLVEMENT.COMPLAINTS_ID
WHERE TABLE_COMPLAINTS.PARTY_ID = 2
ORDER BY TABLE_RESIDENT.FIRST_NAME ASC
```

Comment: but i want to see resident_id firstname, lastname by using the party_id

Comment: like party_id = 2 in table_complaint

Comment: i cant use the table_complaints.party_id = 2 in real time sir because i wiil add more, i mean if i swap  TABLE_COMPLAINTS.RESIDENT_ID = TABLE_RESIDENT.RESIDENT_ID with TABLE_COMPLAINTS.PARTY_ID = TABLE_RESIDENT.RESIDENT_ID i can see the information party_id= 2 but now again in resident_id = 1

Comment: i cant see resident_id = 1